# Regex for strings containing at least 4 unique printable ASCII characters excluding few special characters

Tags: java, regex

I am working on an application, in which input strings must have following properties:

- Contains at least 4 unique characters
- Doesn't contain non-printable ASCII characters
- Doesn't contain comma (,), colon (:), equals sign (=), or space

I came up with below regex, which matches strings with at least 4 unique chars, and all printable ASCII chars excluding space.

```
^([!-~]+)((?!\1)[!-~]+)((?!\1|\2)[!-~]+)((?!\1|\2|\3)[!-~]+)$
```

How do I modify it to exclude comma (,), colon (:), equals sign (=)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java you can make use of [Character Class Subtraction](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-class-operations.html#subtraction_javaruby).

The range can look like `[!-~&&[^,:=]]`

```
^([!-~&&[^,:=]]+)((?!\1)[!-~&&[^,:=]]+)((?!\1|\2)[!-~&&[^,:=]]+)((?!\1|\2|\3)[!-~&&[^,:=]]+)$
```

In Java:

```
String regex = "^([!-~&&[^,:=]]+)((?!\\1)[!-~&&[^,:=]]+)((?!\\1|\\2)[!-~&&[^,:=]]+)((?!\\1|\\2|\\3)[!-~&&[^,:=]]+)$";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RtNGkz/1)

Comment: Did some testing. Doesn't seem to work for `testtesttest`

Comment: @Greengoblin is this not the expected?https://regex101.com/r/GMfbmP/1

Comment: No, because it has less than four unique characters

Comment: @Greengoblin Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/9gRDXV/1